Golang pseudo random string (lots of duplicates)
I am attempting to generate a random string of 5 chars. Every implementation I've tried generates duplicates after a very small sample size (10k-40k). While I understand that programmatically its impossible to generate true random strings I was surprised to see duplicates appearing at such a high frequency.
I have tried several implementations (and variations of those) without luck. Each one generates a duplicate after ~40k strings at most. Given that there are 380,204,032 unique combinations in a 5 char string consisting of [A-Z a-z] I was expecting to be able to generate significantly more strings before encountering a duplicate.
After searching around I found a couple of good sources that were the basis for my implementations

How to generate a random string of a fixed length in Go?

https://www.datagenx.net/2022/10/random-number-genearion-with-cryptorand.html


The 2nd link in particular caught my eye as the author mentioned using the "crypto/rand" package was better at avoiding duplicates. However it seemed to make little difference in how many strings I was able to generate before encountering a duplicate.
Other variations I tried

calling rand.NewSource after each char (instead of each string)
using multiple rand.NewSource and using the output of the 1st to seed the 2nd, 3rd, etc.

Can anyone provide some insight into why these random strings aren't so random and some steps I might be able to take to generate at least 1M strings before encountering a duplicate?
I know I could use a 3rd party library but I would like to avoid that.
func Test_RandomString(t *testing.T) {

    tests := map[string]struct {
        Length       int
        UniuqeValues int
    }{
        "5 x 1,000,000": {
            Length:       5,
            UniuqeValues: 1_000_000,
        },
    }

    for name, test := range tests {
        t.Run(name, func(t *testing.T) {
            actual := utils.RandomString(test.Length)
            assert.Equal(t, test.Length, len(actual))

            values := make(map[string]struct{})
            for count := 0; count < test.UniuqeValues; count++ {
                value := utils.RandomString(test.Length)

                _, found := values[value]
                if found {
                    t.Fatalf("duplicate value found after %v: %v", count, value)
                }

                values[value] = struct{}{}
            }

        })
    }
}

func RandomString_CryptoRand(length int) string {

    const letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    var randomStr []byte = make([]byte, length)

    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {

        idx, _ := rand.Int(rand.Reader, big.NewInt(int64(len(letters))))
        randomStr[i] = letters[idx.Int64()]
    }
    return string(randomStr)
}

func RandomString_MathRand(length int) string {
    var src = rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
    const letterBytes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    sb := strings.Builder{}
    sb.Grow(length)

    for idx := 0; idx < length; idx++ {
        sb.WriteByte(letterBytes[int64(src.Int63())%int64(len(letterBytes))])
    }

    return sb.String()
}


„ I was expecting to be able to generate significantly more strings before encountering a duplicate.“ Can you explain the math behind your expectations? Are you sure your expectations are warranted? Are you aware of the „birthday paradox“?

Besides the fact that your assumptions are incorrect, you are using a new PRNG for each string, so your output is effectively as random as time.Now()

Yes I am aware the "birthday paradox". Although it seems I made another fatal assumption in that the percentage of possible values would remain constant... in the b-day paradox 23 people are needed for a 50% probability (23/365 = 6.3%). So erroneously assumed that to reach a 50% probability when generating a 5 char string would require the same 6.3% (23,952,854) of all possible values (380,204,032).

This is the birthday paradox. You mistakenly assumed that the probability of duplicates is linearly proportional to the pool-size of 525, while in reality the relationship is proportional to the square root. Sqrt(380204032) is 19498 and change, which is pretty much spot-on for what you observed.

Without complicated math, even without the binomial distribution: Let's say, you sampled 20,000 out of 380,204,032 and did not have any duplicates yet. For the next draw, your chances of a duplicate are 20,000/380,204,032 = 0.0001052067
From then on, the chance of a duplicate will continually increase but let's say, it does not. For the next 20,000 draws we'll add this chance per draw and we arrive at 20000/380204032 * 20000 = 1.05 which is > 1.
So even disregarding the chance of getting the duplicate within the first 20,000 draws and disregarding the continuous increase in chance of a double we should expect a duplicate within the first 40k draws.
The problem here is the expectation, not the best Go function or package.
How about producing more random strings then necessary and then drop the duplicates? (maybe see the code here: https://github.com/lehnert-b/spd )

Probabilities can’t exceed 1, so your argument based on multiplication (repeated adding) is fundamentally flawed. The probability that an individual new value dodges all of the values that have already been taken slowly heads towards zero as new outcomes are added.  Probabilities of independent trials are multiplicative though, so the product of a bunch of values that are declining towards zero starts converging to zero quite rapidly as the number of items increases.

My argument was flawed, had I called that a probability. I did not. I followed how many events I expected. Expected numbers are not probabilities.

The “chance” of something happening, when expressed as a proportion, is the empirically-based definition of a probability.

I fail to see where I used the word "chance" for the value 1.05.

I can see what you're trying to do, using non-technical language to produce a statistical result. You're finding a lower bound the expected number of duplicates, and showing it's more than 1. I'm not sure why it follows that the expected number being larger than 1 means you should expect to see a duplicate, although it's highly suggestive when coupled with the intuition that 2 or more duplicates in a single run should be rare compared to seeing 1 duplicate.

@PaulHankin You understood my intentions correctly. However, it is complicated for me to understand your criticism. If the expected number of duplicates is larger then one I expect to see one duplicate rather then be surprised by a duplicate. I expect the expected number especially if I do this many times, as the OP implied he did and the "true" expectation should be larger then the one I computed under false assumptions. (BTW. I am going to edit my post replacing "doubles" with "duplicates").
